# Pandas: how to get a particular group after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to group a dataframe by a column, called 'A', and inspect a particular group.

```
grouped = df.groupby('A', sort=False)
```

However, I don't know how to access a group, for example, I expect that

```
grouped.first()
```

would give me the first group

Or

```
grouped['foo']
```

would give me the group where `A=='foo'`.

However, Pandas doesn't work like that.

I couldn't find a similar example online.

Comment: Marking it as a duplicate means that future searches from other users will work better :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try: `grouped.get_group('foo')`, that is what you need.

Answer (score 4):

```
from io import StringIO # from StringIO... if python 2.X
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv(StringIO("""\
area,core,stratum,conc,qual
A,1,a,8.40,=
A,1,b,3.65,=
A,2,a,10.00,=
A,2,b,4.00,ND
A,3,a,6.64,=
A,3,b,4.96,=
"""), index_col=[0,1,2])

groups = data.groupby(level=['area', 'stratum'])
groups.get_group(('A', 'a')) # make sure it's a tuple

                    conc qual
area core stratum            
A    1    a         8.40    =
     2    a        10.00    =
     3    a         6.64    =
```