# How to get the first group in a groupby of multiple columns?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I've been trying to figure out how I can return just the first group, after I apply groupby.

My code looks like this:

```
gb = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])['col5'].sum()
```

What I want is for that first first group to output. I've been trying the get_group method but it keeps failing (maybe because I am grouping by multiple columns?)

Here is an example of my output:

```
col1  col2  col3   col4  'sum'
 1     34   green   10    0.0
            yellow  30    1.5 
            orange  20    1.1 
 2     89   green   10    3.0 
            yellow   5    0.0 
            orange  10    1.0
```

What I want to be returned is just this:

```
col1  col2  col3   col4  'sum'
 1     34   green   10    0.0
            yellow  30    1.5 
            orange  20    1.1
```

(Note the 'sum' column I just added here to make it clear what that last column was, but pandas does not actually name that column)

Comment: Can you show your dataframe and desired output?

Comment: @chrisz I edited it! Hope that explains what I'm trying to convey.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: how to get a particular group after groupby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702486/pandas-how-to-get-a-particular-group-after-groupby)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can using `get_group` with `groups`

```
g=df.groupby(['col1','col2'])

g.get_group((list(g.groups)[0])).groupby(['col3','col4'])['col5'].sum()
```

Comment: `list(g.groups)[0]` seems suboptimal it would be better to use `next(g.groups)`

Answer (score 5):

```
gb = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])['col5'].sum()

gb.loc[[gb.index.levels[0][0]]])
```

Comment: It works, but it's clunky. Do you think `gb.get_group(...)` should be enhanced to accept integers?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need:

```
idx = df.index.get_level_values(0)
df = df[idx == idx[0]]
```

Or [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df = df.xs(df.index.levels[0][0])

print (df)
                       'sum'
col1 col2 col3   col4       
1    34   green  10      0.0
          yellow 30      1.5
          orange 20      1.1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for group_id, group_df in df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']):
    break
```

iterate over your groupby object and stop after the first iteration. The variables group_id and group_df will contain your first group.

Kind of an ugly workaround but works.