# How to get the first group under certain level of a groupby of multiple columns?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I am interested in the first group in level 2 and want to get all the rows related to it.

Take a look at the example below:

```
col1  col2  col3   col4
 1     34   green   10
            yellow  20
            orange  30
       89   green   40
            yellow  50
            orange  60
 2     89   green   15
            yellow  25
            orange  35
       90   green   45
            yellow  55
            orange  65
```

Please note that the length of row for each level 2 group is not definitely 3.

Now I want to get all the first group under col2, then result is supposed to be:

```
col1  col2  col3   col4
 1     34   green   10
            yellow  20
            orange  30
 2     89   green   15
            yellow  25
            orange  35
```

The example and problem are modified from the question: [How to get the first group in a groupby of multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49799731/how-to-get-the-first-group-in-a-groupby-of-multiple-columns)

I have tried the `get_group` method but it seems not able to address this specific question.

I am wondering if there is any one-line code could solve this kind of question? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
df.groupby(level=[0,2]).head(1)
Out[342]: 
                  col4
col1 col2 col3        
1    34   green     10
          yellow    20
          orange    30
2    89   green     15
          yellow    25
          orange    35
```

Comment: Thank you YOBEN_S! I think your method works clear and efficient for the question. Now I am wondering if it is possible to make some extensions to get the 2nd or other ordinal groups?

Comment: @DOG df[df.groupby(level=[0,2]).cumcount()==N], N here is the nth value you need

Answer (score 3):

There's a quick `stack/unstack` solution:

```
df.unstack('col3').groupby(level=0).head(1).stack('col3')
```

Output:

```
                col4
col1 col2 col3      
1    34   g       10
          o       30
          y       20
2    89   g       15
          o       35
          y       25
```